# NEXTJS Dynamic routes return 404 no matter what

Tags: next.js, dynamic-routing

I'm trying to reach http://localhost:3000/nba/category-slug-3 but I keep getting 404 error. http://localhost:3000/nba works fine but any slug does not work. Am I missing something? Do I need to add/edit another file? I just started using NextJS. At some point I want to be able to use item id's from a mongodb collection as the slug.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you named your page `[slug.js]` when you may have meant to name it `[slug].js`.